# Abort trap 6 malloc

Tags: c

I am trying to make an implementation of an n-ary tree in C. When running it I get the following error:

```
sibling(1143,0x7fff7e925000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f946b4032c8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I am unsure what is causing the error. As it says it seems that I am writing to an object that was freed. But in my code I do not free any of the memory allocated. I am new to c to this confused me very much. I tried debugging with gdb and it says the error is caused by the printTree(); call in main where I am recursively trying to print the tree. Hope you can help me understand the issue :-).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char *name;
  unsigned int utility;
  unsigned int probability; 
} Child;

typedef struct {
  unsigned int level;
  unsigned int player;
  unsigned int nChildren;
  Child *children; 
} Data;

typedef struct sNaryNode{
  Data *data;
  struct sNaryNode *kid; 
  struct sNaryNode *sibling;
} NaryNode;

NaryNode* createNode(Data data){
  NaryNode *newNaryNode = malloc(sizeof (NaryNode*));
  newNaryNode->sibling = NULL;
  newNaryNode->kid = NULL;
  newNaryNode->data = &data;  
  return newNaryNode;
}

NaryNode* addSibling(NaryNode* n, Data data){
  if(n == NULL) return NULL;

  while(n->sibling)
    n = n->sibling;

  return (n->sibling = createNode(data));
}

NaryNode* addChild(NaryNode* n, Data data){
  if(n == NULL) return NULL;
  else if(n->kid)
    return addSibling(n->kid, data);
  else
    return (n->kid = createNode(data));
}

void printTree(NaryNode* n) {
  if(n == NULL) return;

  if(n->sibling) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %s", n->data->level, n->data->player, n->data->nChildren, n->data->children[0].probability, n->data->children[0].utility, n->data->children[0].name);
    printTree(n->sibling);
  }
  else if(n->kid) {
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %s", n->data->level, n->data->player, n->data->nChildren, n->data->children[0].probability, n->data->children[0].utility, n->data->children[0].name);
    printTree(n->kid);
  }
  else {
    printf("The tree was printed\n");
  }
}


int main(void) {
  NaryNode *root = calloc(1, sizeof(NaryNode));
  Data data;
  data.level = 1;
  data.player = 1;
  data.nChildren = 2;
  data.children = calloc(data.nChildren, sizeof data.nChildren);
  data.children[0].probability = 50;
  data.children[0].utility = 1;
  data.children[0].name = "Kom med det første tilbud (anchor)";
  data.children[1].probability = 50;
  data.children[1].utility = 1;
  data.children[1].name = "Afvent modspilleren kommer med første tilbud";
  *root = *createNode(data);
  int i = 0;
  for(i=0; i<root->data->nChildren; i++) {
    addChild(root, data);
  }

  printTree(root);
}
```

Comment: The line `data.children = calloc(data.nChildren, sizeof data.nChildren);` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: `data.children = calloc(data.nChildren, sizeof data.nChildren)` Are you sure that you want sizeof data.nChildren ? try `sizeof *data.children`.

Comment: ......... `sizeof(Child)`

Comment: _"But in my code I do not free any of the memory allocated..."_. Bad idea...

Comment: @Bob__ I am well aware. But I haven't got to make the function to free the tree yet.

Comment: @Stargateur You are right! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various errors in your code.

1. Allocating an incorrectly sized memory block :

   `data.children = calloc(data.nChildren, sizeof data.nChildren);`

   `data.children` is an array of `Child` structures, yet you're allocating structures whose size is equal to `sizeof(unsigned int)`, due to `data.nChildren` being an `unsigned int`.
2. Taking the address of a temporary variable and storing it for later usage :

   `NaryNode* createNode(Data data){
     newNaryNode->data = &data;
   }`

   `data` in `createNode` only exists for as long as the function is running : in this case, you're taking the address of the local variable `data` and storing it in the structure that you're returning for later usage. This is a very bad idea, since this pointer will refer to an object that doesn't exist anymore after the function returns.

   Keep in mind that you don't need to pass a copy of the `Data` object into `createNode` in your current code, since there is really only one `Data` object in the whole program. Thus, you can change the prototype of `createNode` to `createNode(Data* data)`, and pass the address of the `Data` structure that you create in `main`. Doing anything more involved than that, though, would require deep-copying the structure, I think.
3. Incorrectly managing the objects' lifetime.

   `NaryNode *root = calloc(1, sizeof(NaryNode));
   *root = *createNode(data);`

   `createNode` returns an `NaryNode*`. However, you never actually assign it to an `NaryNode*` so that you can free it later. Instead, the pointer to the object that the function returns is known only during the `*root = *createNode(data)` invocation, and irrevocably lost later on. You do, however, retain the contents of the object due to dereferencing it and copying it into `root` : the object itself, however, as returned from `createNode`, is lost and not recoverable, unless pointers to it still exist in the tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. How would you go about storing the data passed into the function createNode in the created node without taking the adress of the data passed into it? And what do you mean when you say the object returned from createNode was 'never freed'? I am pretty new to c so please bear with me if it is stupid questions. :-)

Comment: @jdoe : see the edited answer. Please keep in mind that these are beginner questions, and you're much better off consulting a textbook on C.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another problem. This line does not allocate space for a NaryNode, but only for a *pointer* to a NaryNode:

```
NaryNode *newNaryNode = malloc(sizeof (NaryNode*));
```

Comment: Good catch! Missed this one myself.